# PHP - Regex on numbers, optional decimals and letter

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to "validate" some input from a form on the backend but I kinda got stuck with the required regex. Basically, I want to get a number, no leading zeroes, with an optional decimal and an optional case insensitive thousands notation (1,000 = 1k, 1,000,000 = 1m, 1 billion = 1b ...)
These should match/validate:

```
12.39
12.389k
99.1003b
40.1m
```

These should fail.

```
0.0
12.00b
1e3
2^5
0xFF
12.6z
asdf
```

So far I've tried this:

```
^[1-9]\d*(?:\.\d+)?(?:[kmbt])?$
```

It works but I'm thinking maybe someone could solve this a bit more elegantly than I did.

Comment: Your regex fails to fail on `12.00b`

Comment: Why should pass `99.1003b` and fail on `12.00b` ?

Comment: Your regex isn't taking into account `thousands notation`, is that something you care about? There are no examples in your examples but your description mentions it. or `40.1m` is in your string but denotes `40,100,000`?

Comment: @xpuc7o I think OP does not want trailing zeroes, too.

Comment: You can try with  :  https://regex101.com/r/VWbOQc/1

Comment: I am expecting no thousands separator, i.e `1,000,000` and `1,234` should fail. The "thousands notation I meant in the question is the "Human readable thousands, i.e. 1m is 1million, 1k is 1000, 1b is 1 billion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edit] without thousand separator:

```
/^(?:[1-9][0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]*[1-9])?|0\.[0-9]*[1-9])[kbmt]?$/i
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/7wuoId/1)

---

[Old answer] with thousand separator:

You can do it with:

```
/^(?:[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(?:(,?)[0-9]{3})?(?:\1[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]*[1-9])?|0\.[0-9]*[1-9])[kbmt]?$/i
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/cuU5SI/1)

details:

```
^
(?: # numbers >= 1
    [1-9][0-9]{0,2}
    (?:(,?)[0-9]{3})? # capture an eventual thousand separator
    (?:\1[0-9]{3})*
    # decimal
    (?:\.[0-9]*[1-9])?

  | # numbers < 1
    0\.[0-9]*[1-9]
)[kbmt]?$
```

Comment: Thats a huge number of steps... and will only match on new line will it not?

Comment: @AlexanderHolman: the pattern is designed for a whole string (as the pattern example in the question). The goal is to valid, not to extract. The number of steps is low, about 20 for a valid string and about 25 for an invalid string, it's few.

Comment: the one without the thousand separator works like a charm. Thank you! Just can't really figure out why the one from @ShekharKhairnar [link](https://regex101.com/r/VWbOQc/1) works

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte my bad, I missed the "validate"

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte yep, just noticed that right now after a few test cases. Oh well, it was short and sweet xD

Answer (score 0):

Update in REGEX.

> Below regex will not leading zero allow special characters and characters without specified for notation.
>
> Below regex will allow decimal and integer with thousand and other notation.

```
^[1-9]\d*(\.[0-9]+)?(?:[kmbtKMBT])?$
```

Please check working demo : http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=95995

Comment: This will match `12.00` which is not really desired. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The below should be what you're after:

```
/(\b[1-9][\d\,\.]+([kmbt]?))(\s)/g
```

It matches `12.00b` however... [Here](https://regex101.com/r/tGM4rB/4) is an example of it's use.

Group 1 will contain your exact match.

Comment: works, but as stated matches `12.00b` which I'm trying to avoid altogether.